# React js page URL issue after manually entering in browser

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, routes, http-status-code-404

I am working on a project with is created using react js, after uploading the build, I am facing some strange problem with website url, when I click on link it works fine but when I enter link manually in address bar , it shows 404 not found error. please help me out

**htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

**error in browser**

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Are you  using `react-router`? What kind of back end? Need more details, though it sounds like a client-side vs server-side routing problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: I have used react-router-dom

Comment: ....and on the back end? And did you read the issue I linked? You'll have to look into that

Comment: thanks for your answer but , this solution is not working